# SCALA: executing complete .sql file

Tags: sql, scala

I have a .sql script files and need to execute complete .sql file at once, I have found many related answers, where programmer reads file and execute query one by one.

I require to run .sql file all at-once, like picking up the file and executing in within SCALA.

Currently I am doing it with following code, copied it from copied it from:https://gist.github.com/joe776/831762, my Lead ask me to do it in simple way, instead of executing script line by line, it should get executed as .SQL file

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class ScriptRunner {

    private static final String DEFAULT_DELIMITER = ";";
    private static final String DELIMITER_LINE_REGEX = "(?i)DELIMITER.+";
    private static final String DELIMITER_LINE_SPLIT_REGEX = "(?i)DELIMITER";

    private final Connection connection;
    private final boolean stopOnError;
    private final boolean autoCommit;
    private PrintWriter logWriter = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    private PrintWriter errorLogWriter = new PrintWriter(System.err);
    private String delimiter = DEFAULT_DELIMITER;
    private boolean fullLineDelimiter = false;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     * 
     * @param connection
     * @param autoCommit
     * @param stopOnError
     */
    public ScriptRunner(Connection connection, boolean autoCommit, boolean stopOnError) {
        this.connection = connection;
        this.autoCommit = autoCommit;
        this.stopOnError = stopOnError;
    }

    /**
     * @param delimiter
     * @param fullLineDelimiter
     */
    public void setDelimiter(String delimiter, boolean fullLineDelimiter) {
        this.delimiter = delimiter;
        this.fullLineDelimiter = fullLineDelimiter;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for logWriter property.
     * 
     * @param logWriter
     *        - the new value of the logWriter property
     */
    public void setLogWriter(PrintWriter logWriter) {
        this.logWriter = logWriter;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for errorLogWriter property.
     * 
     * @param errorLogWriter
     *        - the new value of the errorLogWriter property
     */
    public void setErrorLogWriter(PrintWriter errorLogWriter) {
        this.errorLogWriter = errorLogWriter;
    }

    /**
     * Runs an SQL script (read in using the Reader parameter).
     * 
     * @param reader
     *        - the source of the script
     * @throws SQLException
     *         if any SQL errors occur
     * @throws IOException
     *         if there is an error reading from the Reader
     */
    public void runScript(Reader reader) throws IOException, SQLException {
        try {
            boolean originalAutoCommit = connection.getAutoCommit();
            try {
                if (originalAutoCommit != autoCommit) {
                    connection.setAutoCommit(autoCommit);
                }
                runScript(connection, reader);
            } finally {
                connection.setAutoCommit(originalAutoCommit);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error running script.  Cause: " + e, e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs an SQL script (read in using the Reader parameter) using the connection passed in.
     * 
     * @param conn
     *        - the connection to use for the script
     * @param reader
     *        - the source of the script
     * @throws SQLException
     *         if any SQL errors occur
     * @throws IOException
     *         if there is an error reading from the Reader
     */
    private void runScript(Connection conn, Reader reader) throws IOException, SQLException {
        StringBuffer command = null;
        try {
            LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(reader);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (command == null) {
                    command = new StringBuffer();
                }
                String trimmedLine = line.trim();
                if (trimmedLine.startsWith("--")) {
                    println(trimmedLine);
                } else if (trimmedLine.length() < 1 || trimmedLine.startsWith("//")) {
                    // Do nothing
                } else if (trimmedLine.length() < 1 || trimmedLine.startsWith("--")) {
                    // Do nothing
                } else if (!fullLineDelimiter && trimmedLine.endsWith(getDelimiter())
                        || fullLineDelimiter && trimmedLine.equals(getDelimiter())) {

                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(DELIMITER_LINE_REGEX);
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(trimmedLine);
                    if (matcher.matches()) {
                        setDelimiter(trimmedLine.split(DELIMITER_LINE_SPLIT_REGEX)[1].trim(),
                                fullLineDelimiter);
                        line = lineReader.readLine();
                        if (line == null) {
                            break;
                        }
                        trimmedLine = line.trim();
                    }

                    command.append(line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(getDelimiter())));
                    command.append(" ");
                    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

                    println(command);

                    boolean hasResults = false;
                    if (stopOnError) {
                        hasResults = statement.execute(command.toString());
                    } else {
                        try {
                            statement.execute(command.toString());
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.fillInStackTrace();
                            printlnError("Error executing: " + command);
                            printlnError(e);
                        }
                    }

                    if (autoCommit && !conn.getAutoCommit()) {
                        conn.commit();
                    }

                    ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();
                    if (hasResults && rs != null) {
                        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
                        int cols = md.getColumnCount();
                        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
                            String name = md.getColumnLabel(i);
                            print(name + "\t");
                        }
                        println("");
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            for (int i = 1; i <= cols; i++) {
                                String value = rs.getString(i);
                                print(value + "\t");
                            }
                            println("");
                        }
                    }

                    command = null;
                    try {
                        if (rs != null) {
                            rs.close();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        if (statement != null) {
                            statement.close();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        // Ignore to workaround a bug in Jakarta DBCP
                    }
                } else {
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(DELIMITER_LINE_REGEX);
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(trimmedLine);
                    if (matcher.matches()) {
                        setDelimiter(trimmedLine.split(DELIMITER_LINE_SPLIT_REGEX)[1].trim(),
                                fullLineDelimiter);
                        line = lineReader.readLine();
                        if (line == null) {
                            break;
                        }
                        trimmedLine = line.trim();
                    }
                    command.append(line);
                    command.append(" ");
                }
            }
            if (!autoCommit) {
                conn.commit();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.fillInStackTrace();
            printlnError("Error executing: " + command);
            printlnError(e);
            throw e;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.fillInStackTrace();
            printlnError("Error executing: " + command);
            printlnError(e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            conn.rollback();
            flush();
        }
    }

    private String getDelimiter() {
        return delimiter;
    }

    private void print(Object o) {
        if (logWriter != null) {
            logWriter.print(o);
        }
    }

    private void println(Object o) {
        if (logWriter != null) {
            logWriter.println(o);
        }
    }

    private void printlnError(Object o) {
        if (errorLogWriter != null) {
            errorLogWriter.println(o);
        }
    }

    private void flush() {
        if (logWriter != null) {
            logWriter.flush();
        }
        if (errorLogWriter != null) {
            errorLogWriter.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Please show the code you have written so far. For instance: open file, read line by line. Connect to DB, get connection. For every line of text, execute SQL statement given by that line of text. Then tell us what does not work in your code.

Comment: That's definitely not scala code...

Comment: You are right, that's my question, how can I execute a .sql file all at once in Scala

Answer (score 1):

Why did you tag "scala"?
To execute a whole sql file at once:
    `sql < myFile.sql`

Edit: as Cyrille Corpet pointed out, you can perform this command directly via scala

```
import sys.process._
"sql < myfile.sql" !
```

Comment: Well, I am working with scalatest, have to run setup before actual test, which involves executing .sql file, can't just run that manually everytime

Comment: No need to do it by hand: `import sys.process._   "sql < myFile.sql" !`